# can you connect 2 water meters into 1

Tags: plumbing

I have an older home that used to be a 2 family-side by side,  It has 2 individual water systems and 2 individual water meters.  Is it possible to eliminate the older system and meter by connecting the plumbing system to the better side of the house thus having only 1 meter, 1 water bill, 1 hot water heater, etc?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to work with your water supply utility company. Call them first before you do anything, they will come out and disconnect your supply line from **their** meter.